# can not ping internet when launch instance cirros on mitaka

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I'm new to openstack, I follow eveything in this manual: http://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-rdo/keystone.html (http://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/inst...) and I install on 2 node (controller - compute), choose option 2 (Self-service networks) . After install I can create public network, private network, router - launch instance . I had edited rule for security group, but I can not ping from cirros instance to internet . This is error when I ping router gateway from controller node:

```
[root@controller ~]# ping 192.168.77.42
PING 192.168.77.42 (192.168.77.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.77.21 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.77.21 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.77.21 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.77.21 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
```

please tell me what i missing when install mitaka. I think problem bettwen router and public gateway. thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

1. verify your private Network settings like DNS address ...
2. If you use Neutron make sure that you correctly configured your
   Network Interface Card and external bridge

   3. verify firewall settings

here is a good tutorial that may help you :
[Installing Openstack Mitaka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOlIB323c8s)